# How to force custom Rails route to use :id instead of :<model>_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-routes

I defined the following custom Rails route in routes.rb:

```
resources :projects do
    get 'members' 
end
```

This results in the following route (output from rake routes):

```
project_members GET        /projects/:project_id/members(.:format)
```

What I would like, though, is for the route to map to this instead (change :project_id to :id)

```
project_members GET        /projects/:id/members(.:format)
```

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is members a nested resource? If so define it as one, and understand that this is why you have `:project_id` in the route, because `:id` in a nested resource is used by the final child item - you can't have multiple nested resources all using the same variable to define their id.

```
resources :projects do 
  resources :members
end
```

Add in a third level of nesting and it becomes a bit clearer to explain:

```
resources :projects do 
  resources :members do
    resources :colours
  end
end
```

With this nesting you could visit `app/projects/:project_id/members/:member_id/colours/:id` which would be served by the `colours` controller, which knows that `:id` defines an instance of that controllers model, and any other named id's belong to other resources.

Otherwise I think you just need to define it as a member method:

```
resources :projects do
  member do 
    get 'members'
  end
end
```

This tells the route that the action `members` is a non-resource action belonging to an instance of `project`, which I think should sort you out, but be sure it's the right thing to do.

See section [2.10 of Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: No, members is not a nested resource in this case. For the sake of the question, just consider 'members' as some action on a project.

Comment: @AndyR. The last code block in my answer should do what you want then.

Comment: Sorry, it was confusing since the "member" keyword happens to be the same name as the action. But yes, it works. Thank you!